# full balance of account of all items together

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, constructor

Trying to get the full balance of all four together at the bottom.

```java
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount(100.00, "abc111", "woods");
        //System.out.println(b1);
                
        BankAccount b2 = new BankAccount(200.00, "deff222", "gates");
        
        BankAccount b3 = new BankAccount(300.00, "ghi333", "bezos");
        
        BankAccount b4 = new BankAccount(400.00, "jkl444", "zuckerberg");
        
        System.out.println(b1.getLastName());
        System.out.println(b1.getBalanceCdn());
        b1.withdraw(5.0);
        System.out.println(b1.getAccountNumber());
        System.out.println(b1.getBalanceCdn());
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        
        System.out.println(b2.getLastName());
        System.out.println(b2.getBalanceCdn());
        b2.deposit(22.22);
        System.out.println(b2.getAccountNumber());
        System.out.println(b2.getBalanceCdn());
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        
        System.out.println(b3.getLastName());
        System.out.println(b3.getBalanceCdn());
        b3.deposit(5.00);
        System.out.println(b3.getAccountNumber());
        System.out.println(b3.getBalanceCdn());
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        
        System.out.println(b4.getLastName());
        System.out.println(b4.getBalanceCdn());
        System.out.println(b4.getAccountNumber());
        System.out.println(b4.getBalanceCdn());
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        
        String b1getBalanceCdn = "$95.00";
        System.out.println("Customer Woods has "+ b1getBalanceCdn + " in account #abc111");
    
        String b2getBalanceCdn = "$222.22";
        System.out.println("Customer Gates has "+ b2getBalanceCdn + " in account #deff222");
    
        String b3getBalanceCdn = "$305.00";
        System.out.println("Customer Bezos has "+ b3getBalanceCdn + " in account #ghi333");
    
        String b4getBalanceCdn = "$400.00";
        System.out.println("Customer Zuckerberg has "+ b4getBalanceCdn + " in account #jkl444");
    
        System.out.println(b1.getBalanceCdn());
        System.out.println(b2.getBalanceCdn());
        System.out.println(b3.getBalanceCdn());
        System.out.println(b4.getBalanceCdn());
        int x = (int) 95.00;
        int y = (int) 222.22;
        int a = (int) 305.00;
        int b = (int) 400.00;
        int sum = x + y + a + b;
        System.out.println("Total bank balance in all accounts for Bank Of Kanada is "+ sum);
    
    }
}
```

I get this print out.

```
Customer Woods has $95.00 in account #abc111
Customer Gates has $222.22 in account #deff222
Customer Bezos has $305.00 in account #ghi333
Customer Zuckerberg has $400.00 in account #jkl444
95.0
222.22
305.0
400.0
Total bank balance in all accounts for Bank Of Kanada is 1022
```

I need this.

```
Customer Woods has $95.00 in account #abc111
Customer Gates has $222.22 in account #deff222
Customer Bezos has $305.00 in account #ghi333
Customer Zuckerberg has $400.00 in account #jkl444
Total bank balance in all accounts for Bank of Kanada is 1022.22
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: this is Java code, why have you also included the `javascript` tag - they are completely different languages

Comment: you are using integer value for the total while you need to use decimal to keep the cents

Comment: Why do you expect _cents_ are available  in the `sum` after explicit casting of floating point numbers to `int`?  Why the balance numbers are hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly casting floating-point values to integer value.

```
int x = (int) 95.00; //Stores 95
int y = (int) 222.22; //Stores 222 here you loose the precision of 0.22
int a = (int) 305.00;// Stores 305
int b = (int) 400.00;// stores 400
int sum = x + y + a + b; // 95 + 222 + 305 + 400 = 1022
```

So what you need is a clear understanding of `primitive datatypes in java` ,when and where to use them.
In this case you can use float primitive datatype.

```
 float x = 95.0;
 float y = 222.22;
 float a = 305.0;
 float b = 400.0;
 float sum = x + y + a +b;
```

Also you need to follow a proper java tutorial for better understanding of java code.